# Services not registering with Eureka Server using Owin, SteelToe/Autofac running as a Windows Service

Tags: c#, owin, autofac, netflix-eureka, steeltoe

Web Services are not registering with Eureka Server from a OWIN SelfHosted console application with Steeltoe/Autofac libraries running as a Windows Service.

//container.StartDiscoveryClient(); does register with Eureka server in another ASP.net app but not in the Console app described above.

The Services runs correctly running in Postman as a client getting the responses we are looking for.

Startup.cs:

ApplicationConfig.RegisterConfig("development");

```
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            builder.Register(c => new Logger()).As<ILogger>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterDiscoveryClient(ApplicationConfig.Configuration);
            builder.RegisterType<Diw.Persist.DiwData>().As<Diw.Persist.IDiwData>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<EwsService>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<HubData.Persist.HubDataData>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<Icm.Persist.IcmData>().InstancePerRequest();

            var container = builder.Build();
            config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

            app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
            app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
```

Services should show under instances registered with Eureka Server

Comment: Where is `StartDiscoveryClient()` called in this app?

Comment: I added that line of code back under app.UseWebApi(config); and run it but I navigate to the Eureka Server there's no entry for the service name there.

Comment: exception:  Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsMonitor`1[Steeltoe.Discovery.Eureka.EurekaClientOptions] clientConfig' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsMonitor`1[Steeltoe.Discovery.Eureka.EurekaClientOptions], Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsMonitor`1[Steeltoe.Discovery.Eureka.EurekaInstanceOptions], Steeltoe.Discovery.Eureka.EurekaApplicationInfoManager, Steeltoe.Discovery.Eureka.Transport.IEurekaHttpClient, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory, Steeltoe.Discovery.Eureka.IEurekaDiscoveryClientHandlerProvider)

Comment: Try adding `builder.RegisterOptions();` before `RegisterDiscoveryClient`

Comment: I added it and still does not register with Eureka server.

Comment: Did that at least resolve the exception you shared earlier?

Answer (score 0):

There are possibly more factors in play than what you've shared so far, so I went ahead and updated one of the Steeltoe samples to also work with a self-hosted OWIN service so you could at least see a basic working example. https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Samples/tree/2.x/Discovery/src/AspDotNetAutofac

Self-Hosting OWIN can be tricky, for best results you probably don't want it running under IIS at all, so make sure you're running it as a console app during development (as this Steeltoe sample does)

Comment: The difference here is that I am running this as a Windows Service so my program.cs looks like this:      
static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
                new SafeConnectWinService()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }

Comment: That is a difference, but I don't think that is the key difference... I've now added a Windows service that runs an OWIN server to that sample, it seems to be registering fine for me, though I'd long forgotten how much fun Windows services are to debug. If you're not already, you might want to consider something like Topshelf (http://topshelf-project.com/) so that you can build and debug a console app and only worry about deploying as a Windows Service

Comment: Cool!!  I got your sample to register with Eureka.  I will create a new project with the Nuget packages in the sample, which are a lot less than mine, and try that.   Thanks for your help!!